# Netflix Conductor SQS

Tags: amazon-sqs, netflix, netflix-conductor

Has anyone successfully integrated Netflix Conductor with AWS SQS? 
I have tried below steps but the workflow is not triggered.

1. Create SQS queue
2. Added AWS creds to environment
3. Registered tasks, workflows and the event listener below

```json
{
  "name": "sqs_event_listener",
  "event": "sqs:name_of_sqs_queue",
  "condition": "true",
  "active": true,
  "actions": [{
    "action": "start_workflow",
    "start_workflow": {
      "name": "mywf"
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late to help the original poster, but adding a response to improve the hive mind of SO:

In your Conductor `application.properties` file, make sure you have the following values

```
conductor.default-event-queue.type=sqs
conductor.event-queues.sqs.enabled=true
conductor.event-queues.sqs.authorized-accounts=(your AWS account number)
```

We need to update `annotations-processor/awssqs-event-queue/src/main/java/com/netflix/conductor/SQSEventQueueConfiguration.java`

```java
    @Bean
    AWSCredentialsProvider createAWSCredentialsProvider() {
        return new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
    }
```

With this configuration in Conductor, you can now restart your instance, and your event should receive events from the SQS message queue.

For a full post with workflow and tasks SENDING ans RECEIVING SQS messages - check out: https://orkes.io/content/docs/how-tos/Tasks/SQS-event-task